# How to convert multiple objects in an array to a new object?

Tags: javascript, node.js, arrays, object

Let's say I got an Array below:

```
[
  { type: 'senior', schoolName: 'school-A', country: 'America' },
  { type: 'senior', schoolName: 'school-B', country: 'England' },
  { type: 'junior', schoolName: 'school-C', country: 'German' },
  { type: 'junior', schoolName: 'school-D', country: 'Italy' }, 
]
```

How can I convert the array above to an object as shown in below:

```
{
  senior: {
    America: 'school-A', 
    England: 'school-B'
  }, 
  junior: {
    German: 'school-C', 
    Italy: 'school-D'
  }
}
```

What is the syntactically cleanest way to accomplish this?

Thanks for any help!!

Comment: What if there are two senior schools in America?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

One way could be to [reduce](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce) your array of objects to a single object. For each iteration you can accumulate your object (initially starting as an empty object `{}`), to contain the current `type` key along with the new key-value pair for the country and schoolName. By using the [spread syntax `...`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax) you can merge the previously seen object at the `type` key (from your current accumulated object) with the new object you're constructing.

See code comments in the example below:

```js
const arr = [ { type: 'senior', schoolName: 'school-A', country: 'America' }, { type: 'senior', schoolName: 'school-B', country: 'England' }, { type: 'junior', schoolName: 'school-C', country: 'German' }, { type: 'junior', schoolName: 'school-D', country: 'Italy' }, ];

const res = arr.reduce((acc, {type, schoolName, country}) => ({ // obtain the kys from the current object using destructuring assignment
  ...acc, // merge the current object stored in acc into the current object `{}` we're building
  [type]: { // using "computed property names"
    ...acc[type], // merge inner object (still worrks when acc[type] === undefined) 
    [country]: schoolName
  }
}), {}); // start with an initial empty object `{}` that we'll accumulate to
console.log(res);
```

Spreading your object each iteration could be seen as inefficient, so you can accumulate the single object reference instead (which at this point, might be worth looking at using a standard `for` loop for readability instead):

```js
const arr = [ { type: 'senior', schoolName: 'school-A', country: 'America' }, { type: 'senior', schoolName: 'school-B', country: 'England' }, { type: 'junior', schoolName: 'school-C', country: 'German' }, { type: 'junior', schoolName: 'school-D', country: 'Italy' }, ];

const res = arr.reduce((acc, {type, schoolName, country}) => {
  if(!acc[type]) acc[type] = {};
  acc[type][country] = schoolName;
  return acc;
}, {});
console.log(res);
```

Answer (score 1):

I think this is a simple and readable solution to your problem (if multiple instances of the same `country` show up in the same `type` the last occurence will override all previous occurences)

```js
let data = [
  { type: 'senior', schoolName: 'school-A', country: 'America' },
  { type: 'senior', schoolName: 'school-B', country: 'England' },
  { type: 'junior', schoolName: 'school-C', country: 'German' },
  { type: 'junior', schoolName: 'school-D', country: 'Italy' }, 
];

let res = {};

data.forEach(e => {
  if(!res[e.type])
    res[e.type] = {};
    
  res[e.type][e.country] = e.schoolName;
});

console.log(res);
```

Comment: Having a for each in this way does produce side-effects, it's manipulates an object outside of it's scope, namely `res`. Since the OP asked for syntactically cleanest way, I would argue a `forEach` isn't the best (then again, I voted to close the question as it is opinion based because of that sentence)